# Simple symmetric random walk - is my assumption correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $a,k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a<k$, and let $(S_n)$ denote a simple symmetric random walk starting at $a$. We know that $(S_n)$ is a martingale, of course. Consider the stopping time $\tau=\inf\{ n\geq 1 | S_n=0 \quad \vee\quad S_n=k \}$. Then we know that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$.

Now, what I need is this: $(S_n)$ is bounded up to time $\tau$, i.e. there exists some $M<\infty$ such that

$|X_n|1_{n\leq\tau}\leq M1_{n\geq\tau}$ for all $n$.

Am I completely wrong in saying that this is obvious? Is it even true?

Comment: The very minute you ask "Am I wrong in saying this is obvious?", it appears to me that you are indeed wrong. But let me ask: Why is it obvious to you?

Comment: do you mean that $\vee$ to be a $\wedge$ ?

Comment: What is $X_n$? (And +1 to @Lord_Farin for the first part of their comment.)